# Proof of limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n>0\forall  n\in \mathbb N$, and converges to a positive limit, then 
lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1$.

I  need to prove this statement. We have recently been looking at Cauchy sequences, Bolzano-Wierestrass Theorem, subsequences and it should be related in some way but I am not sure how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove or use the fact: If $x_n\to x, y_n\to y>0, y_n>0$, then $\frac{x_n}{y_n}\to \frac{x}{y}$

Comment: Ahh I see, so am I simply able to use the quotient rule followed by the shift rule and then we're done?

Comment: @MathsUndergrad Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a_n)$ converges, it is bounded, say $r\le a_n\le s$ for all $n$, with $r>0$ because the limit $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is positive.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$; then
$$
\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right|=\frac{|a_n-a_{n+1}|}{a_{n+1}}\le\frac{|a_n-l|+|a_{n+1}-l|}{r}
$$
Since there exists $\bar{n}$ such that, for all $n\ge\bar{n}$,
$$
|a_{n}-l|\le \frac{r\varepsilon}{2}
$$
you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Every subsequence of a convergent sequence will converge to the same point...

So, $a_n\to a>0$ will implies $a_{n+1}$ also converges to $a$.

Now $\cfrac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}\to \cfrac a a=1$